# Knex join selection and performance (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I reached the strange problem. If I use this query below (with havingRaw query), the response time is about 15 sec. Without havingRaw, the response time is about 0.5 sec. Any help?

```
database.table(`resources`)
.innerJoin((query) => {
          query
 .columns([
       'res_int_id',
       database.raw('sum(price) as pricesum'),
       database.raw('sum(discount_price) as discountsum')])
 .from(`prices`)
.whereRaw('? < dateto and ? > datefrom', [dateFrom, dateTo])
.groupBy('res_int_id')
.havingRaw('sum(price) > ? and sum(price) < ?', params['priceRange'])
.as('NewPrice')
 }, `resources.id_rsrs`, 'NewPrice.res_int_id')
```

Comment: Only to add what I noticed soon, that if I used only one condition into havingRaw (e.g. 'sum(price) < ?', 15000), the response time is 0.5 sec also.

Comment: The same code on other machines doesn't produce this problem (the same database). Strange situation.